# LDAP authentication password encryption

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, cryptography, ldap

I am using LDAP technique to authenticate user in my web application  . For accessing LDAP service it is accepting clear text string password . How to encrypt and decrypt user password , to avoid sending actual password in network .My network channel is SSL secured .
.

Comment: SSL/TLS secures a TCP connection (seen as a client & server socket during development), not the network. Unless you use the connection to tunnel a network using an additional protocol of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to encrypt and decrypt user password, to avoid sending actual password in network. My network channel is SSL secured.

You've answered your own question. SSL does it for you.

Comment: SSL secures the network , but will my password not be visible in sending  parameter ?

Comment: @Sumeet SSL secures the *connection.* The password goes over the connection. Ergo SSL secures the password. Your questions don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Summet, are you saying that the interface between the client and your application is over https and you  want to encrypt the connection between your application and the ldapserver?

If yes, then you need to use ldaps and not ldap between your application and the ldapserver.